# What tools will help when removing a glued down floor?

Tags: flooring, floor, adhesive, removal, hardwood

We are having a very hard time getting a glued down floor up. We have tried using large scrapers, a crowbar, and a hammer, none have been effective.

Are there any other recommended tools that we should try? We have an air compressor so pneumatic tool recommendations would also be welcomed.

Comment: Can you let us know the type of flooring that you are removing and the type of subflooring that it is glued to?

Comment: A very large pot, stove, and towels.

Answer (score 2):

If it is vinyl sheet flooring, I pulled up as much as possible to get to the layer the glue is bonded to and used paint remover. It soaked through the layers, softened the glue where I could use a 4" drywall taping knife to remove it to the subfloor.

Comment: You may need to try a few different solvents : [Trouble removing vinyl tile and underlayment from wood flooring](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39530/trouble-removing-vinyl-tile-and-underlayment-from-wood-flooring)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use floor scraper machine, hand held, MK Diamond 14 Amp 1.5 HP Manual Floor Scraper 167676.
You might be able to go to a tool rental location as they may have these, we use Sun Belt Tool Rentals here, but there are others.

These mechanical scrapers are loud and create heat to scrape the carpet in strips, you may need another machine to remove the adhesive which essentially looks like a floor polisher.

If all else fails you can always call a company like Stanley Steemer or Coit.  They may provide these flooring removal services for you as I know they do in my area.

Good Luck

Comment: Or an SDS rotary hammer with a chisel attachment. [What power tool is the best and fastest to take up floor tile?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85991/what-power-tool-is-the-best-and-fastest-to-take-up-floor-tile)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the kind of glue (ie., those cheap, self adhereing tiles), a heat gun (or maybe a hair dryer) could help (do not use heat in conjunction with paint thinner). Also, many tiles use water based glues... which you could use on concrete, but if you have wood subfloor, you don't want to (water) damage the wood.

Alternative: For the amount of work, you should consider adding new subflooring on over the old floor.

Comment: Or just remove it and replace with new subfloor.